# factanal help and how to code using formula

Tags: r

I've got this equation to apply in R

```
fit <- factanal (f[filename : x+n], factors , rotation='varimax')
```

what do i put where? i know to put my filename where it says, but i'm getting my data from an excel table that i've made about suburbs in my city and different qualities about the suburbs and i've uploaded that to r

Comment: You are *much* more likely to get help if you use proper English (grammar & spelling) and avoid "internet speak". Also please properly format your question and code (use the editing tools). Perhaps also take a look at [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Comment: If this is an assignment, then hopefully your teachers have given you information on the tools you'll need to solve it - things like vectors, how to read in data files and work with the resulting dataframe. Go over your notes carefully, then if you're still stuck, try to explain exactly how and where.

Comment: Hi Marius, i haven't been given any more information other than the codes however they aren't working for my data. I missed class one day which was when we were learning R. I'm a beginner with this all and don't know what parts of my formula to replace with what sections of my data.

Comment: I've imported my table from excel to r. I'm just struggling to find how to apply the equation to my data. For example my table has a list of suburbs down the side and then a list of suburb characteristics along the top. Say there's 120 suburb rows, and 28 characteristic columns.

Comment: Oops posted those too early didn't realise pressing return adds the comment. So my equation is: fit <- factanal (f[filename : x+n], factors , rotation='varimax')

Should my equation look a little like this?

fit <- factanal (FileName [ 1 : 28], "Quality 1", "Quality 2" "etc" , rotation='varimax')

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `?factanal` to understand the meaning of every function argument.

For example,

1. the first argument `x` needs to be a numeric `matrix` or an object that can be coerced to a numeric `matrix` (like a `data.frame`).
2. the second argument `factors` specifies the number of factors in the factor analysis.

Here is a example based on some randomly generated data.

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017)
df <- data.frame(
    a = runif(10),
    b = runif(10),
    c = runif(10),
    d = runif(10),
    e = runif(10))

# Perform factor analysis
fit <- factanal(df, factors = 2, rotation = 'varimax')
#
#Call:
#factanal(x = df, factors = 2, rotation = "varimax")
#
#Uniquenesses:
#    a     b     c     d     e
#0.162 0.639 0.005 0.397 0.054
#
#Loadings:
#  Factor1 Factor2
#a          0.914
#b  0.601
#c -0.990   0.120
#d          0.777
#e  0.820   0.523
#
#               Factor1 Factor2
#SS loadings      2.017   1.727
#Proportion Var   0.403   0.345
#Cumulative Var   0.403   0.749
#
#Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.
#The chi square statistic is 1.14 on 1 degree of freedom.
#The p-value is 0.285
```

I don't know how you read in data from an Excel sheet (is it an XLS/XLSX or CSV file?), but you need to ensure that the first argument in `factanal` is a numeric `matrix` or `data.frame`.